# Prencher vários campos input com valores de outros campos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, formulário

Tenho três linhas com quatro campos `input` do tipo `time`, e quero criar um botão para que as duas linhas abaixo possam ser preenchidas igual a primeira.

Estou seguindo [esta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19940434/4734177), e adaptei para pegar por `classe` ao invés de `id`, então já consigo preencher vários campos à partir de um, mas quero, à partir de um botão, disponibilizar o preenchimento da linha abaixo com o valor dos outros quatro da linha acima (vide imagem abaixo).

O HTML das linhas:

```
    <label id="Cseg2" class="hora">Linha 1:</label>
    <label for="Cseg3">Entrada:</label>
    <input type="time" id="Cseg3" name="Tsegs">
    <label for="Cseg4">Saída:</label>
    <input type="time" id="Cseg4" name="Tsegss">
    <label for="Cseg5">Retorno:</label>
    <input type="time" id="Cseg5" name="Tsegsss">
    <label for="Cseg6">Saída:</label>
    <input type="time" id="Cseg6" name="Tsegssss">
    <br>
    <label id="Cter2" class="hora">Linha 2:</label>
    <label for="Cter3">Entrada:</label>
    <input type="time" id="Cter3" name="Tter">
    <label for="Cter4">Saída:</label>
    <input type="time" id="Cter4" name="Tters">
    <label for="Cter5">Retorno:</label>
    <input type="time" id="Cter5" name="Tterss">
    <label for="Cter6">Saída:</label>
    <input type="time" id="Cter6" name="Ttersss">
    <br>
    <label id="Cqua2" class="hora">Linha 3:</label>
    <label for="Cqua3">Entrada:</label>
    <input type="time" id="Cqua3" name="Tqua">
    <label for="Cqua4">Saída:</label>
    <input type="time" id="Cqua4" name="Tquas">
    <label for="Cqua5">Retorno:</label>
    <input type="time" id="Cqua5" name="Tquass">
    <label for="Cqua6">Saída:</label>
    <input type="time" id="Cqua6" name="Tquasss">
    <br>
```

Por enquanto consegui chegar até aqui mexendo no script do SOen:

```js
var tags = [];

$(function() {
    
    $('#tagAdd').click(function(){
        //get the tag value and trim the spaces
        var tVal = $('#tagEntry').val().trim();
        if(tVal == '')
            return;
        
        //verify tag not already saved
        for(var i=0;i<tags.length;i++)
            if(tags[i] == tVal)
                return;
        
        //add the tag to the array
        tags.push(tVal);
        
        //set the tags entry box
        $('.tagsEntered').val(tags.join(', '));
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <strong>Enter your tag and click add</strong>
    <br/>
    <input type="time" id="tagEntry" />
    <button id="tagAdd">Add</button>
</div>

<div>
    <strong>Entered Tags</strong>
    <br/>
    <input type="time" class="tagsEntered"/>
</div>
    
<div>
    <strong>Entered Tags 2</strong>
    <br/>
    <input type="time" class="tagsEntered"/>
</div>
<div>
    <strong>Entered Tags3</strong>
    <br/>
    <input type="time" class="tagsEntered"/>
</div>
```

O resultado que espero é algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A solução pode ser em javascript simples, com jQuery, ou com mesmo com o Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem vários modos de implementar isso. A minha solução é a seguinte:

- Adicionar uma classe `linhaX` em cada `input`, onde X é o número da linha.
- Adicionar um botão em cada linha identificado com uma classe `repeat`. O botão tem um atributo `data-source` que é a linha de onde vem os dados a serem copiados, e `data-target`, que é a linha de destino da cópia.
- A lógica do JS é basicamente a seguinte: para cada `input` de `source`, copiar o valor para o correspondente em `target` (que tem o mesmo índice).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.repeat').click(function(){
    var target = $('.' + $(this).data('target'));
    $('.' + $(this).data('source')).each(function(index, value){
      target.eq(index).val($(this).val());
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="Cseg2" class="hora">Linha 1:</label>
<label for="Cseg3">Entrada:</label>
<input type="time" id="Cseg3" name="Tsegs" class="linha1">
<label for="Cseg4">Saída:</label>
<input type="time" id="Cseg4" name="Tsegss" class="linha1">
<label for="Cseg5">Retorno:</label>
<input type="time" id="Cseg5" name="Tsegsss" class="linha1">
<label for="Cseg6">Saída:</label>
<input type="time" id="Cseg6" name="Tsegssss" class="linha1">
<br>
<label id="Cter2" class="hora">Linha 2:</label>
<label for="Cter3">Entrada:</label>
<input type="time" id="Cter3" name="Tter" class="linha2">
<label for="Cter4">Saída:</label>
<input type="time" id="Cter4" name="Tters" class="linha2">
<label for="Cter5">Retorno:</label>
<input type="time" id="Cter5" name="Tterss" class="linha2">
<label for="Cter6">Saída:</label>
<input type="time" id="Cter6" name="Ttersss" class="linha2">
<button type="button" class="repeat" data-source="linha1" data-target="linha2">Repetir linha anterior</button>
<br>
<label id="Cqua2" class="hora">Linha 3:</label>
<label for="Cqua3">Entrada:</label>
<input type="time" id="Cqua3" name="Tqua" class="linha3">
<label for="Cqua4">Saída:</label>
<input type="time" id="Cqua4" name="Tquas" class="linha3">
<label for="Cqua5">Retorno:</label>
<input type="time" id="Cqua5" name="Tquass" class="linha3">
<label for="Cqua6">Saída:</label>
<input type="time" id="Cqua6" name="Tquasss" class="linha3">
<button type="button" class="repeat" data-source="linha2" data-target="linha3">Repetir linha anterior</button>
```

Comment: Lucas, o script está funcionando legal, mas além de incluir corretamente os valores nos outros campos, ele está enviando meu formulário quando clico no botão. Como posso fazer para que ele não envie o formulário, apenas preencha os campos. Ah, e no phpstorm no trecho `(function(index, value)` aparece a mensagem `unused parameter value`. Preciso adaptar alguma coisa? Agradeço desde já, valeu.

Comment: Ah, consegui com `onclick="addItem(); return false;"`. ^^ Fonte: http://stackoverflow.com/a/932657/4734177

Comment: Nah, achei que tinha funcionado mas acho que foi só o lag. :/

Comment: Tinha esquecido de incluir o JS... não está funcionando ainda, mas acho que to no caminho aqui. :-)

Comment: LOL a resposta abaixo http://stackoverflow.com/a/10836076/4734177 simplificou tudo: somente incluir no HTML `type="button"`. :-)

Comment: Isso aí. Por padrão, o botão submete. Modifiquei ali na resposta